# Armco iron B-H curves

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science

I've been looking for B-H curves for Armco iron.
 I'd love to find one with good resolution. Does anyone know where you could acquire one? I've been looking in various Armco ingot supplieres but no luck. Maybe some publication or other place that I could look for?

The only good one I've found yet:

[image: B-H curves for Armco ingot iron and 1020 steel, implemented in magnetic simulation models.]

Comment: This is clearly an engineering question. The magnetization curve will depend on manufacturing details and the treatment of the material, and getting a higher resolution curve of some random sample that anyone might send you won't give you anything more reliable to work with for your project than you have. Worst case you will have to measure this yourself on your final product. That's certainly what I would do if it mattered with any precision.